# MDI child form in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with an MDI container marked as true. This form is a parent form which has a child form. In the child form I use this code for loading it in maximized size.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

I use this codes for showing the child form :

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.Show();
```

And also child form is fixed single so that it won't be able to resize. But however i disable maximize button it will disapper and can be restore down.

Comment: Are you asking how to ensure your form is always maximized and never made less than full screen?

Comment: Yes. I just want to show this form as maximized and disable restore down.

Comment: In that case, don't be mean to your users.  If they want to restore the form to non-maximized state let them.  What is  your compelling reason for stopping them from doing that?

Comment: because i don't want to use table layout panel. if they want to change the size of the form so i should use table layout panel.

Comment: I think it's worth the time and effort to actually layout your controls properly rather than positioning everything absolutely and then preventing users from ever resizing the form.  After you start to do it enough you get pretty good at it and it won't take you much extra time, and it **greatly** improves the user experience.  After all your content won't always be fixed in size, users won't always have the same size screen/resolution, or different users may want to show more/less than a fixed format would allow.

Comment: You don't need to use TableLayoutPanel to make a form resizable. All you need is Dock and Anchor.

Comment: Winforms forgets to throw exceptions when you use properties like this.  The native Windows MDI support code doesn't support this, it has a hard requirement that child windows have a normal sizable frame with the regular buttons.  If this is important to you then MDI is not the proper windowing model to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f2.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? When you say it isn't working, what do you mean?  What does it do?

Comment: how ever i use f2.MinimizeBox = false it will show the control and can be restore down. btw i don't have problem with minimize. i don't want to restore down.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
f2.ControlBox = False;
```

That could hide both the MaximumBox and MinimumBox but not the Close Button.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, what ended up doing the trick was handling the OnMove event and resetting the visibilities there (even though they are already set to false). Not sure why that works, but it did for me.

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: The problem is that when a child MDI form is maximized, the control box will display even when ControlBox, MaximizeBox etc. are set to false, correct?